Oracle Query Ignores Local Index on Partitioned Table
I have a partitioned table SHARED_RAW_RE_GL78 in Oracle, partitioned by the column MONTHID. The table has around 300 million rows, with about 2 million new rows inserted daily. I created a local index on the CUST_DIVISION column in each partition, expecting Oracle to use this index in my query. However, when I run the query, Oracle performs a full table scan instead of using the index.
CREATE INDEX IDX_CUST_DIVISION_1 ON "KTC"."SHARED_RAW_RE_GL78" (CUST_DIVISION)
LOCAL
(
    PARTITION MONTHID_01,
    PARTITION MONTHID_02,
    PARTITION MONTHID_03,
    PARTITION MONTHID_04,
    PARTITION MONTHID_05,
    PARTITION MONTHID_06,
    PARTITION MONTHID_07,
    PARTITION MONTHID_08,
    PARTITION MONTHID_09,
    PARTITION MONTHID_10,
    PARTITION MONTHID_11,
    PARTITION MONTHID_12
);

----the query-----
SELECT GL_CODE, SUM(NET_LCY) 
FROM 
(
  SELECT GL_CODE, NET_LCY 
  FROM "KTC"."SHARED_RAW_RE_GL78"
  WHERE MONTHID=202408 AND CUST_DIVISION = 'KHCN'
) a
GROUP BY GL_CODE;

THIS is my execution plan of the code



Id
Operation
Name
Rows
Bytes
Cost (CPU)
Time
Pstart
Pstop




0
SELECT STATEMENT

279
7533
665K (1)
00:00:27




1
HASH GROUP BY

279
7533
665K (1)
00:00:27




2
PARTITION LIST SINGLE

59M
1520M
664K (1)
00:00:26
8
8


3
TABLE ACCESS FULL
SHARED_RAW_RE_GL78
59M
1520M
664K (1)
00:00:26
8
8



From this execution plan, it’s clear that Oracle is performing a full table scan on partition 8, even though the query filters on MONTHID (partition key) and CUST_DIVISION (indexed column). I expected it to use the local index on CUST_DIVISION.

Why is Oracle ignoring the local index on CUST_DIVISION?
Is there a specific reason why the optimizer prefers a full table
scan in this case?
Are there any optimizer hints or adjustments that could force Oracle
to use the index?

Any advice on how to improve this indexing strategy would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Jan's answer is pretty decent. My answer is basically: don't worry about it. Index access isn't always the best method. Oracle will use the index if it thinks it's profitable to do so, not simply because it's there. Make sure you have stats gathered and move on. The only time you should be concerned with execution plans is when things are running long and you need to tune the queries.  If that's the case with your query (it's running long) I suggest hinting it for parallelism : select /*+ parallel(8) */ gl_code...

Yes, i will use parallel query. Thanks Paul

The Oracle Optimizer's decision to favour a full table scan over the local index on CUST_DIVISION typically stems from a combination of cost estimates and the selectivity of the index compared to scanning the entire partition. Here’s a summary of the probable causes:
Higher Cost of Index Access 
Compared to Full Scan The Optimizer may have determined that using the index incurs a greater cost than a full scan. For each row matching the MONTHID, Oracle would first need to access the index, then fetch the actual data from the table—potentially a substantial I/O operation. Given that there are around 59 million rows in the partition, if a large portion of these match CUST_DIVISION = 'KHCN', Oracle may consider a full scan to be more efficient.
Low Selectivity on CUST_DIVISION 
If CUST_DIVISION has a large number of distinct values but also a high frequency of the value 'KHCN', the Optimizer may view the index as suboptimal. Indexes tend to perform best when they narrow down results to a smaller subset of rows; hence, low selectivity may lead Oracle to forego the index.
Data Skew and Incomplete Statistics 
Outdated or insufficient statistics on the table or index could lead the Optimizer to misjudge the cost of using the index. If the statistics do not accurately reflect the current data distribution in CUST_DIVISION, Oracle might deem the index ineffective.
Preference for Parallel Execution 
Oracle might bypass the index if it determines that a parallel full scan would provide faster results. When the Optimizer senses that parallel execution will reduce overall time, it may favour a full table scan.
These are some of the common factors that could be influencing Oracle’s choice, particularly with large datasets or when data distribution is uneven.
You can try to force Oracle to use the index with the INDEX hint:
SELECT /*+ INDEX(SHARED_RAW_RE_GL78 IDX_CUST_DIVISION_1) */ GL_CODE, SUM(NET_LCY)
FROM 


He can force the index but it's probably a bad idea to do so. It is likely OP doesn't understand that indexes aren't always the best access method.

Thanks Jan Suchanek , i use hint to force my query then i see the cost is higher. Now i get it!

Use partition name to make it faster
SELECT GL_CODE, SUM(NET_LCY)
FROM
(
SELECT GL_CODE, NET_LCY
FROM "KTC"."SHARED_RAW_RE_GL78" PARTITION (MONTHID_08)
WHERE CUST_DIVISION = 'KHCN'
) a
GROUP BY GL_CODE;

That is no faster than pruning partitions with an equality predicate on a partition key value.
